# Hook that is initialized with an empty array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Let's say we want to make Hook with type `string[]`, and no elements. I am doing

```
const def: string[] = []
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(def);
```

Which works. But, I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this in one line only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string[]>([]);
```